# Difference between date value change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

Link: [Query (duration) different between data value change](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46641/query-duration-different-between-data-value-change/46698#46698?newreg=bccece5c9643492cb80f47fda84225a4)

I am trying to write a query that would get me the duration of a status in a table. This query needs to work in SQL Server 2008.

Say I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE RateTable(
    [Key] [int],
    [Value] varchar(10) NULL,
    [RecordDate] [DateTime] NULL
    )
GO

INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-01');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-02');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'xyz','2012-01-02');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'xyz','2012-01-05');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-05');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-08');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-10');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-11');
INSERT INTO [RateTable] VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-12');
GO
```

So it contains the rows that follow:

```
Key Value RecordDate
--- ----- ----------
1   abc   2012-01-01
1   abc   2012-01-02
1   xyz   2012-01-02
1   xyz   2012-01-05
1   abc   2012-01-05
1   abc   2012-01-08
2   abc   2012-01-10
2   abc   2012-01-11
2   abc   2012-01-12
```

I would like to have output (the result set) for the value `'abc'` only, as shown below:

```
Value StartDate  EndDate  
----- ---------- ----------    
1     2012-01-01 2012-01-02 
1     2012-01-05 2012-01-08
2     2012-01-10 2012-01-12
```

Comment: Why would your output not include `1, '2012-01-05', '2012-01-08'`? And, why just one row for ID = 2, instead of `2, '2012-01-10', '2012-01-11'` and `2, '2012-01-11', '2012-01-12'`?

Comment: From your desired output - for each set of consecutive entries for a given ID where the value is `abc`, you want the first date and the last date. What do you want to see if there's only one record: for instance, add an additional entry: Key = `3`; value = `abc`, date = `2012-01-11`. Should there be no entry (only one record), or should we treat this as the first and last (returning value = `3`, startdate = `2012-01-11`, enddate = `2012-01-11`)?

Answer (score 3):

Yet another grouping or window. It is a bit longer due SQL Server 2008 doesn't support LAG functions and it must be simulated.

> ```
> -- add a row number to simulate a lag function
> with a as
> (
>     select [key], value, recorddate, row_number() over (partition by [key],value order by [key], value, recorddate) rn 
>     from ratetable 
>     where value = 'abc' 
> )
>   -- set reset points
>   , b as
>   (
>       select t1.[key], t1.value, t1.recorddate, t2.recorddate rd2,
>              case when t2.recorddate is null
>                        or t1.[key] <> t2.[key] 
>                        or datediff (day, t2.recorddate, t1.recorddate) > 1 then 1 end is_reset
>       from a t1
>       left join a t2
>       on t2.[key] = t1.[key] 
>       and t2.rn = t1.rn -1
>
>   )
>     -- generate groups  
>     , c as
>     (
>         select [key], [value], recorddate, count(is_reset) over (order by recorddate) grp
>         from   b
>     )
>     -- max/min of each group
>     select [Key], min(recorddate) as StartDate, max(recorddate) as EndDate 
>     from c
>     group by [Key], grp;
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> Key | StartDate           | EndDate            
> --: | :------------------ | :------------------
>   1 | 01/01/2012 00:00:00 | 02/01/2012 00:00:00
>   1 | 05/01/2012 00:00:00 | 05/01/2012 00:00:00
>   1 | 08/01/2012 00:00:00 | 08/01/2012 00:00:00
>   2 | 10/01/2012 00:00:00 | 12/01/2012 00:00:00
>
> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Check this,

```
DECLARE  @RateTable TABLE(
    [Key] [int],
    [Value] varchar(10) NULL,
    [RecordDate] [DateTime] NULL
    )


INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-01');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-02');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'xyz','2012-01-02');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'xyz','2012-01-05');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-05');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (1,'abc','2012-01-08');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-10');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-11');
INSERT INTO @RateTable VALUES (2,'abc','2012-01-12');
declare @input varchar(50)='abc'
;

WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY (
                    SELECT NULL
                    )
            ) rn
    FROM @RateTable
    WHERE value = @input
    )
    ,cte1
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,dateadd(day, [key], [RecordDate]) ENDDATE
    FROM cte
    WHERE rn % 2 <> 0
    )
SELECT c.*
FROM (
    SELECT c.value
        ,c.[RecordDate] [start_date]
        ,CASE 
            WHEN ca.[RecordDate] IS NULL
                THEN c.[RecordDate]
            ELSE ca.[RecordDate]
            END ENDDATE
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY CASE 
                WHEN ca.[RecordDate] IS NULL
                    THEN c.[RecordDate]
                ELSE ca.[RecordDate]
                END ORDER BY c.[RecordDate]
            ) rn1
    FROM cte1 c
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT [RecordDate]
        FROM cte1 c1
        WHERE c.value = c1.value
            AND c.enddate = c1.[RecordDate]
        ) ca
    ) c
WHERE rn1 = 1
```